# How can I track the version of Python in Raspberry PI O/S

Tags: python-3, version-control

I'm trying to keep both a Mac (Mojave - 2.7.16 by default) and a VM Raspberry Pi Desktop up to date with Python so that it matches that on the Pi but other than firing up a Pi and running

```
python3 --version
```

I'm a bit stuck to find the version released in the latest Buster releases.

I've looked in the [release notes](http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_armhf/release_notes.txt) and checked on [GITHUB](https://github.com/raspberrypi) but I must be missing something or my GoogleFu is weak today!

I'm not sure if this level of accuracy for the core Python programs is needed (I dabble at the mo) but I'm having issues with library versions so think I may as well go the whole hog and match the core as well.

Longer term I'm going to go back to Visual Studio Code and remote debugging but for now I'm deploying on Zeros and cannot run the remote debug due to ARM version limitations.

I do not want to get involved in something like [BuildRoot](https://buildroot.org) if there is a simple way to find out...

I know an other option is to freeze the deployment platform but that feels like running Windows 7 when 10 is out... No comments on Catalina / Big Sur vs Mojave I like a stable development platform.

Comment: Since minor versions (the x in 3.x.y) should be backward compatible, the best approach is probably pick a minimum appropriate to the machines you are working on and the stuff you are doing, then just include a version check in your code.  Try to use as low a value as possible, ie., unless you have a specific reason ("I need this feature from 3.7+"), don't pick 3.7, pick 3.2 or 3.0, etc.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. I note macOS doesn't even ship with Python3

Comment: @Milliways I know that the Mac only comes with v2 - I load V3.x.x from the Python site directly fine.  What I need to keep track of is the version of Python that is shipped with the Pi operating system so I can keep in step without having to build a SD card every time there is an update from RPF/RPT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://wiki.debian.org/Python

Debian Bullseye contains 2.7, 3.7, 3.8

Debian Buster contains Python 2.7, 3.7

Debian Stretch contains Python 2.7, 3.5

Debian Jessie contains Python 2.7, 3.4